# Give variable style properties react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a custom progress bar using React. I have a calculated percentage, I want to set as a width of some div element. Currently I tried it using Tailwind CSS:

```
<div className={"p-1 w-[" + percentage + "%]"}></div>
```

But it does not work. So how can I apply this kind of variable styling in React?

Comment: did you tried using ``  string, `p-1 w-[${percentage}%]` maybe can solve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the needed Tailwind classes, create a variable to store the classes for the progress bar:

```
const progressBarClasses = `p-1 w-${progress}`
```

Assign the classes to the div like this:

```
<div className={progressBarClasses}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put expressions in plain JSX, you must use the special curly braces syntax to evaluate an expression and it will resolve to a value:

```
<div className={"p-1 w-[" + percentage + "%]"}></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, editied the question - already got that - doesnt work

Comment: In Tailwind CSS, you can set a custom width and unit using square brackets like it shows here in the official docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#arbitrary-values so your code seems to be correct. However, if you still have an issue, check if the value of `percentage` is what you expect it to be. You can also try using the `style` property to set the width of the element: `<div className={"p-1"} style={{ width: percentage + "%" }}></div>`.

Comment: That is not the problem. The classname is even shown in the souce code in the browser, sometimes it works until I refresh..

Comment: I might be able to identify the issue if I check all of your code. Is it possible to share your code in a pen or sth?